# Unity Scope to read XMP metadata from local files

Tags: unity, application-development, scopes

I have seen various tutorials on writing Unity Scopes, including the one on developer.ubuntu.com However, they all appear to concentrate on scopes that download data from various web services.

I am looking for a scope that can read XMP from jpg files on the local filesystem. Is such a thing doable?